# WPF ListBox Selection change binding

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

In one of the WPF interview, I was asked to create a simple contact management WPF application. The application is a 2 pane contact management application, with the left pane showing the list of contacts and the right being a detail view for the selected contact in the left pane. I created this using MVVM instead of binding it in code behind. I used SelectedItem of ListBox to show details of selected contact in right hand side pane.

I used following

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts,Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact}"
         Margin="10"
         ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}">
```

The SelectedContact is the property of VM bound to this user control. Following is part of VM code

```
public ContactInformation SelectedContact 
{
    get { return _selectedContact; }
    set
    {
        if(_selectedContact != value) 
        {
            _selectedContact = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnContactChanged();
        }
        
    }
}

public void OnContactChanged()
{
    if(ContactChangedEvent != null)
    {
        ContactChangedEvent(this,SelectedContact);
    }
}
```

The code reviewer (interviewer) thought that this is bizarre code and binding is not correct. I would like to know what the problem is with this code.

I could have used interaction triggers but that would have required downloading interaction package. Other solution is to use SelectionChanged event but implementation will be in code behind and not in VM.

Am I missing anything? Is this binding incorrect? Understanding my mistake will help me a lot in improving my WPF skills.

Comment: At least, `Mode=TwoWay` of ItemsSource's binding is strange. Do you expect that propery is to be changed in the view?

Comment: Yes. We should be able to add contacts to it. My main problem is not ItemsSource but how to take action on selected item change?

Comment: When you drive with your car and pick up your friends will your car change because someone enters/leave the car or is it just the content that changes? That is like here, the `ItemsSource` itself will never be changed by the view

Comment: What is the reason for that `ContactChangedEvent` in the ViewModel? There is already a notifictaion with `PropertyChanged` and that is enough for binding. This is also very unlikely for a ViewModel

Comment: MVVM does not mean *No code in code-behind* but you should use the power of binding and every code in code-behind should only be related to UI presentation

Comment: This is not a complete master-detail view. There is code missing. The feedback you can get on your implementation is therefore limited and probably not relevant as the full context could change some assessments being made. I also assume that you have not provided the full summary of your exercise instructions (which is also very important in order to understand where you made bad decisions.

Answer (score -1):

*"I created this using MVVM instead of binding it in code behind"* - MVVM is not meant to replace code-behind with data binding.

MVVM is a design pattern with the goal to introduce application components to help separate the application (model) from the UI (view) by providing an interface (view model). MVVM is concerned about responsibilities of the types in an application and the direction of the data flow or MVVM component dependencies.

As an official design pattern, MVVM does not care about XAML or C# or compiler features like partial classes. As a design pattern it is not allowed to care about such details, that's part of the definition of a design pattern. A design pattern must be language and compiler agnostic.

The only purpose of a design pattern is to solve a specific problem. Therefore, it's always extremely helpful to understand the problem that a pattern was designed to solve before you try to understand the design pattern itself.

It's very likely that the main test of your task was forcing you to discuss your solution in order to get an idea of your understanding of WPF and software design skills and of course communication skills. And to see how you approach a project.

I think your biggest mistake was not to discuss your solution with the interviewer. Had you done so, you would now know what exactly he didn't like about your solution or you would have been able to convince him of your solution.

To discuss your code sample:
The explicit `TwoWay` binding mode on the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property tells the interviewer that you are likely not fully understanding the mechanics behind data binding. A `Binding` is triggered when the property value changes. A control that presents data is always a passive data view. It never has any interest to actively change the property value of the `ItemsSource` or the data source in general. In other words. `ListBox` will never change the value of `ItemsSource`:

```cs
// The following code will never happen. 
// Therefore, there will be no value to send back to the binding source,
// which makes a `TwoWay` binding mode redundant.
// The `ItemsControl` only gets a `ItemsSource` value from the binding source.
this.ItemsSource = new List<object>();
```

Whether you should handle the `SelectionChanged` event in code-behind or bind to the `SelectedItem` property depends on what the code that handles the change is responsible for. A simple Master-Detail view doesn't even require any of that.
Again, MVVM does not mean "put all the application code into the view model classes". The view model classes are the most boring classes in your application as they only get data from the model to present it to the view and get user manipulated data from the view to send it back to the model.

If I were you, I would have asked what *simple* means. If this means whether you could create the application with or without MVVM. Especially if you get a time frame for the exercise it is very ikportant to not add unessecary complexity. Being able to identify and avoid uneccessary complexity is also a very important skill set for a developer of a time crunched project.

While the exercise pretends to be trivial and innocent it reveals alot about you, about your programming skills, architecture skills, project management skills, self management skills, communication skills, etc.
I believe that once you are aware of this you can present yourself much better and effectively.

A simple Master-Deatil view that uses MVVM could look as follows:

**Contact.cs**

```cs
class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Contact (string name, string lastName, string mailAddress)
  {
    // TODO::Initialize properties
  }

  public string Name { get; }
  public string LastName { get; }
  public string MailAddress { get; }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollectionyContact> Contacts { get; }

  // The reference to a model class.
  // This class knows how to read and write Contact entities 
  // from/to a data source of te application. 

  private ContactsRepository ContactsRepository { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.ContactsRepository = new ContactsRepository();
    this.Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
  }

  public void Initialize()
    => this.Contacts = this.ContactsRepository.GetContacts();
}
```

**MainWIndow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();    
    this.DataContext = this.MainViewModel;
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }  

  public void OnLoaded()
  {
    this.MainViewModel.Initialize();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="MasterView"
             Grid.Column="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name" />

    <StackPanel x:Name="DetailsView"
                Grid.Column="1"
                DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MasterView, Path=SelectedItem}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding MailAddress}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Good luck with your next interview!

Comment: I appreciate this description. Thank you.